# ListView retorna apenas um item do Cursor

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, listview, cursor

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com um problema no meu projeto. Eu tenho um ListView que recebe informações do Cursor e logo em seguida manda para o Adaptador, porém ele está puxando apenas um registro do meu banco de dados, vocês poderiam me ajudar ?

```
public void lprod(SQLiteDatabase db){
    ArrayList<modelListprod> prod = new ArrayList<modelListprod>();

    listprod = new modelListprod();

    String descricao = "";
    String ean = "";
    String status = "";
    Double precoprod;
    String categoria;
    int cod;

    SQLiteDatabase d5 = dadosOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor5 = d5.query("produto" , new String[]{"descricao", "ean", "status", "precoprod", "codigocateg", "cod"},null, null, null   ,null,null,null);
   if (cursor5 != null) {
       if (cursor5.moveToFirst()) {

           do {


               descricao = cursor5.getString(0);
               ean = cursor5.getString(1);
               status = cursor5.getString(2);
               precoprod = cursor5.getDouble(3);
               categoria = cursor5.getString(4);
               cod = cursor5.getInt(5);
               listprod.setDescricao(descricao);
               listprod.setCategoria(categoria);
               listprod.setEan(ean);
               listprod.setPreco(precoprod);
               listprod.setStatus(status);
               listprod.getId(cod);


               //listadeprod.add(listprod);
           } while (cursor5.moveToNext());
       }
   }

    listadeprod.add(listprod);
    AdapterProd adapterProd = new AdapterProd(this, listadeprod);
    listproduto.setAdapter(adapterProd);

}
```

Comment: Quantos listprod está a criar? Quantas vezes está a adicionar um listprod ao array?

Comment: o listprod ele manda as informações para o Model do adaptador, a variável que lê o listview é o listproduto, e o listprod ele só está adicionando 1 vez.

Comment: Então está explicado porque a lista só tem um.

Comment: Porém o listprod ele é colocado apenas uma vez, por que ele envia as informações do banco de dados para o modelListProd e através desse model ele conversa com o layout de listar_produtos para encaixar os dados do banco em seus devidos lugares. Se eu repetir ou colocar alguma condição nele não funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por cada registo no cursor um novo **modelListprod** deve ser adicionado ao array **prod**.

Veja os comentários no código.

```
public void lprod(SQLiteDatabase db){
    ArrayList<modelListprod> prod = new ArrayList<modelListprod>();

    //Passa para dentro do while
    //listprod = new modelListprod();

    String descricao = "";
    String ean = "";
    String status = "";
    Double precoprod;
    String categoria;
    int cod;

    SQLiteDatabase d5 = dadosOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor5 = d5.query("produto" , new String[]{"descricao", "ean", "status", "precoprod", "codigocateg", "cod"},null, null, null   ,null,null,null);
   if (cursor5 != null) {
       if (cursor5.moveToFirst()) {

           do {

               //uma nova instância por cada registo
               listprod = new modelListprod();

               descricao = cursor5.getString(0);
               ean = cursor5.getString(1);
               status = cursor5.getString(2);
               precoprod = cursor5.getDouble(3);
               categoria = cursor5.getString(4);
               cod = cursor5.getInt(5);
               listprod.setDescricao(descricao);
               listprod.setCategoria(categoria);
               listprod.setEan(ean);
               listprod.setPreco(precoprod);
               listprod.setStatus(status);
               listprod.getId(cod);

               //Adiciona ao array
               listadeprod.add(listprod);

           } while (cursor5.moveToNext());
       }
   }
    //Passa para dentro do while
    //listadeprod.add(listprod);

    AdapterProd adapterProd = new AdapterProd(this, listadeprod);
    listproduto.setAdapter(adapterProd);
}
```

Haveria mais coisas para alterar, nomeadamente o nome de algumas variáveis e restringir a responsabilidade do método apenas a preencher o array e retorná-lo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, você me ajudou muito

Comment: Espero que tenha percebido onde estava o problema. Agora já deve fazer sentido, para você, o meu primeiro comentário na pergunta.

Comment: Sim, fez sim, eu acabei me confundindo e por isso eu passei apenas uma vez então ele não entrava em um laço. Mas muito obrigado.